# How to configure apache2 to serve my website with HTTPS?

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, apache-http-server, ssl, https

I need to test my website in HTTPS, because some functionalities (i.e. geolocation) are accessible only with secured connection using Firefox.

I was trying to follow [this help](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/httpd.html#https-configuration), but I did not succeed in achieving what I need.

So far, I did:

```
sudo a2enmod ssl
sudo a2ensite default-ssl
sudo systemctl restart apache2.service
```

This should have enabled my webserver for secure connection on the standard port (443) with a self-signed certificate. Indeed, I can browse the apache index page by typing `https://localhost`.

However, I am now kind of left alone in congifuring my website's `.conf` file.

I tried to copy and modify `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf` like so:

**(webgis.conf)**

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost _default_:443>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        #   SSL Engine Switch:
        #   Enable/Disable SSL for this virtual host.
        SSLEngine on

        SSLCertificateFile  /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key

        Alias "/webgis" "/home/umberto/Documents/apps/projects/wineshire"
        <Directory "/home/umberto/Documents/apps/projects/wineshire">
            Require all granted
        </Directory>

    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Then I enabled my site by doing:

```
sudo a2ensite webgis
sudo systemctl restart apache2.service
```

All I get when I try to access `https://localhost/webgis/ol/webmap/wms_19_spatialite.html` (where the resource is placed), is `404 not found`.

I think the error is not only a matter of configuring HTTPS, but more related to wrong .conf settings. Anyway, can anybody help me understanding what am I doing wrong, or in general, what's wrong in the steps I performed?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT 1**

So after trying to figure out what was wrong with the `.conf` file, I decided to simply add an alias and a directory to my new site directly in the `default-ssl.conf` and guess what? It now works (I am on Firefox)...

So basically the way I was setting my `.conf` (which is shown above) is not correct apparently... Looking forward to sloving this mistery...

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure the self-signed certificate will be deemed acceptable by Firefox anyway. What you need is a true certificate, easy to obtain/use with ["Let'sencrypt"](https://letsencrypt.org/).

DigitalOcean has a [pretty good tutorial on installing the LetsEncrypt certificate and its auto-renewal on an Ubuntu/Apache server](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-apache-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-16-04).

This is how I added HTTPS to my server, and it was really a piece of cake.

Comment: Thanks. Will look at it asap. Anyway, don't know why I am not getting "untrusted site" or similar message, but 404. Do you think my conf is wrong somewhere? Also, mine is really a test env, so maybe I should use another browser maybe.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am trying to access the website from the server itself and from my phone in the same LAN (using the ip), so maybe in this specific case the self signed is fine?